# Textbox filter in WPF Datagrid columns headers

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid defined like this in my XAML :

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DtgPoshResults" Style="{StaticResource DatagridResults}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=PoshResults, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ClipboardCopyMode="{Binding ClipBoardCopyMode}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterDatagridCell}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItemPoshResults, Mode=TwoWay}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1}"/>
```

To get a textbox in each column header (in order to filter by column), I use a `Template`.

My Datagrid has a dynamic number of columns (that can vary each time I start a command) :

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#FF444444">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="DtgResultsColumnName" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="White" Margin="5,5,5,0"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBox Width="100" Margin="5" Text="{Binding DataContext.TextFilterColumn, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Hyperlink Foreground="White" Command="{Binding DataContext.FilterColumnName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DtgResultsColumnName, Path=Text}">
                                Filter
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

After starting my command, the Datagrid displays results and looks like this :

[image]

When typing *"lo"* in the first textbox and clicking on *"Filter"*, it works and I only get the line which is *"localhost"* but when the Datagrid is refreshed, all the textboxes are filled with the word *"lo"* :

[image]

I can't define a different Text Binding for each textbox as I have a dynamic number of columns so I don't know how to avoid that all textboxes in the headers get the same text when filter is applied.

Do you know how can I fix this?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: How are the number of columns changing? It looks like you are letting the datagrid auto-generate columns based on the properties of the items source class?  Can we see that?

Comment: You are binding all textboxes to the same `TextFilterColumn` of the view model of the window so of course they will contain the same text. If you want a filter textbox per column, you need to define a template per column instead of reusing the same one. You also need to define a "filter" property per column in the view model.

Comment: @mm8 : yes I know and that's where I'm stuck because my Datagrid is by default with Autogenerated columns as the colmuns displayed in the Datagrid are not always the same. I can filter all my colmuns without any problem, it filter the column where I'm typing text but I'm looking for a way to not retrieve the same text in all the textboxes.

Comment: Maybe I have no choice to do some code-behind instead of MVVM?

Comment: @chancea : yes the ItemsSource of the Datagrid is autogenerated. I have a gridview with checkboxes above the Datagrid and the results displayed depend on the checkboxes checked. 1 row checked = 1 column in the datagrid  so 3 rows checked displays 3 columns in the Datagrid, etc.

Comment: If the columns are auto-generated you should create the templates programmatically in the code-behind.

Comment: @Manu can we see that code?

Comment: @chancea : I succeeded in doing what I wanted with code behind. Thanks.